# What is required knowledge for Android application development?

Tags: android

I am wondering what I will require knowledge of to effectively develop an Android application in addition to where these skills can be acquired.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Buy a computer, get internet service, find a Java tutorial, learn Java, read the Android docs, find some Android tutorials, learn Android, buy an Android device to test on, write application, test said application on aforementioned Android device

Comment: Please just start with Google, there are loads of guides and tutorials out there. Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions - please come back when you've had a go and are properly stuck.

Comment: One of the prerequisites is not to  post anything to Stack Overlow until you have a real thing to ask about. This is because such posts will distract you from learning Android.

Comment: Have you considered googling it before asking here?

Comment: I have googled, I wanted preferred resources per language.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are a beginner I would recommend you to start with [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/download/)(Mobile application development framework).

This required only a basic knowledge of HTML,CSS and JS.

Comment: You really shouldn't. Don't do it. Go native instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well you'll need to know Java but other than that it should be pretty simple.  I built my first app about a month ago and only knew Java.  It takes time to learn Java though.

Here is some links that might be helpful 
http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=31

http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=6

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I have heard TNB is only really if you have already learned Java prior to using it